# Spring and jtds.jdbc.Driver parameters

Tags: spring, properties, parameters, jtds

I have Spring application with MS SQL Server using jtds, how can I find all parameters for the data source?
Now I have only:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

I want to set also: timeout.login, timeout.connection, timeout.query and timeout.reconnect

Comment: List of properties for the jtds jdbc driver: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

`DriverManagerDataSource` isn't intended to be used as a production ready `DataSource` implementation. It is nice for testing or quickly showing an application but it should/must end there. For production you want to use a real `DataSource` which does connection pooling and a lot of other things.

Instead of the `DriverManagerDataSource` you want to use something like [tomcat-jdbc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) or [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) for a datasource. Those will all allow you to set various options.

If you really want to keep using the `DriverManagerDataSource` pass the properties into the `connectionProperties` element. See [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat) for the properties which you can set.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props>
            <prop entry="socketTimeout">${timeout.connection}</prop>
            <prop entry="loginTimeout">${timeout.login}</prop>                               
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't a proper connection pool I would expect a value for `timeout.reconnect` to be useless. A connection is opened at the start of a transaction and closed as soon as the transaction has committed.

Comment: Just tried for both I receive:
java.sql.SQLException: The SOCKETTIMEOUT connection property is invalid.
and
java.sql.SQLException: The LOGINTIMEOUT connection property is invalid.

Comment: As I already mentioned you actually shouldn't be using this. Not sure what the exact names are, just did a guess based on the faq. Also you do have those properties `timeout.connection` etc. in your properties file?

Comment: Yes, I have them in my properties file

Comment: May be I can accompish this using hibernate C3P0, am I close? I don't want to create real data source, because I have to load the parameteres from external properties file and it was easy using spring

Comment: And why wouldn't you be able to use a proper connection pool and still have an external configuration file? This is what I have been doing for about 12 years now, with different datasource implementations.

Comment: Ok and how can I load the tomcat datasource from external properties file using spring?

Comment: You just configure it like you do the `DriverManagerDataSource` it doesn't matter what bean it is everything works for every bean. Regardless of the library or the package it is in.

Comment: But what kind of data source do I need to create, because if I create a data source in my tomcat and try to lookup it in spring context this way:

<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DatabaseName"/>
</bean>

I'm not able to set the properties from the properties file

Comment: You don't create a datasource in tomcat, you just create it in your spring configuration file. Instead of a `DriverManagerDataSource` you are going to use the tomcat, bonecp or whatever implementation you choose classes.